# How to store images in filesystem

Tags: php, mysql, macos

So I am creating a online store where people can upload images for their products. Previously I stored the images as BLOBs in a MySQL database, but in Stack Overflow I've seen that many people suggest storing the images in a filesystem and putting the "path" to the image in the database. This might be too vague of a question, but how do you do this? (I'm on a Mac, using PHP)

Thank you!

**EDIT**

So after some research I discovered Content Delivery Systems... Are these file systems, or are file systems their own computers that you can store images on, which is what I (possibly miss)understood? I am finding many tutorials on file systems, but they don't tell me where the images go to...

Comment: I think you mean storing the images on the web server and putting the path like /img/IMAGENAME.png in the database?

Comment: @Dustin Yes, I think...

Comment: There are many tutorials covering this exact subject- many more than cover the blob method

Answer (score 0):

So from what I can gather from your question I think I would recommend using something like SimpleImage (https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage) and then doing something like this

```
$image = new SimpleImage($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
if($image->get_width() > 250){ $image->fit_to_width(250); }
$image->save("profile_photos/pic-$user_id-$random_string-1.png");

$update_reg = mysql_query("UPDATE registration SET profile_photo = 'profile_photos/pic-$user_id-$random_string-1.png' WHERE id='$user_id'") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

This is a very rough outline directly pulled from one of my projects but hopefully this will help give you the base you'll need.